# Reducer in React Shows: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I needed to convert some data in my reducer from an array to object. So I used `Object.keys` to do so. But I started to get this error that it cannot convert undefined.

After troubleshooting for quite a bit I have reduced the code in my reducer to its simplest form as below and I'm still seeing the same error. Can someone please advise what is the issue here? Ofcourse now that I have removed `Object.keys` I'm seeing a slightly different error but the main issue seems to be the same. The object in the state is undefined.

Thank you!

Just to add something when I do a  `console.log(state.collections["hats"]);`
right before the switch statement, it shows the data as expected i.e the object/value for the "hats" key

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hats' of undefined
```

My simplified Reducer code:

```
import SHOP_DATA from '../../data/shop.data.js';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  collections:  {
    hats:{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Hats',
      routeName: 'hats',
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Brown Brim',
          price: 25
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Blue Beanie',
          price: 18
        }
      ]
    },
    sneakers: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Sneakers',
      routeName: 'sneakers',
      items: [
        {
          id: 10,
          name: 'Adidas NMD',
          price: 220
        },
        {
          id: 11,
          name: 'Adidas Yeezy',
          price: 280
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const collectionsReducer = (state= INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch(action.type) {
    default:
      return ["hats", "sneakers"].map(key => state.collections[key]);

  }
}

export default collectionsReducer;
```

Comment: I think your state got mutated to an empty object. Can you try putting a console.log(state) inside your collectionsReducer?

Comment: @dp.js It prints fine, shows collections data with hats and sneakers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the reducer logic like below then it will work

switch(action.type) {
default:
return ["hats", "sneakers"].map(key =>INITIAL_STATE['collections'][key])
}

Thank you

Comment: state is equal to INITIAL_STATE and I need to iterate over collections keys not the INITIAL_STATE keys, so no it did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no key named sneakers, thats why it is returning undefined

Comment: you are right but still don't think that is the issue. i have added sneakers to the collection and i still get the same error (updated my code above). Thanks